# Group By Statement giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, subquery

I have the following code, and I am using to query a CMMS system database for reporting reasons. If I remove the `Group by` it will run, but it counts all runs returned by the `Where` statement. I'm guessing it's because I'm not using the `Group By` statement. When I add it in I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

If any body can point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
USE [Maint5k]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PMs_Past_Due_Count]    Script Date: 3/21/2017 11:08:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Hicks,Clayton>
-- Create date: <2017,03,06>
-- Description: <Pulls open Maintennace Reactive Work Orders for the current week>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PMs_Past_Due_Count]
as
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT
  woJob.JobID
  ,woJob.FullDescription
  ,woJob.DueDate
  ,syJobType.Code AS [syJobType Code]
  ,syJobStatus.Code AS [syJobStatus Code]
  ,emLabour.LabourFirstName AS [First Name]
  ,emLabour.LabourSurName AS [Last Name]
  ,wojob.LabourID 
  ,(Select count(wojob.LabourID) as 'Count_LabourID' from woJob 
    INNER JOIN syJobType
        ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID
    INNER JOIN syJobStatus
        ON woJob.JobStatusID = syJobStatus.JobStatusID
    INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour]
        ON woJob.LabourID = emLabour.LabourID

Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED') 
        group by wojob.LabourID) as CountLabourIDs
 FROM
  woJob
    INNER JOIN syJobType
        ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID
    INNER JOIN syJobStatus
        ON woJob.JobStatusID = syJobStatus.JobStatusID
    INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour]
        ON woJob.LabourID = emLabour.LabourID

Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED') 
'
```

Comment: the error is correct because you have multiple groups under wojob and counting them is basically giving you the count per group as to the over all count...

Comment: so what's the goal for the subquery?

Comment: This seems to be a complicated way to get a *group count*, try `count(*) over (partition by wojob.LabourID)` instead.

Comment: @dnoeth subquery should only return one result/column... so grouping it dynamically will give more than 1 result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+Subquery+returned+more+than+1+value.+This+is+not+permitted+when+the+subquery+follows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same join/where twice, this is probably the same as a *Group Count*:

```
SELECT
  woJob.JobID
  ,woJob.FullDescription
  ,woJob.DueDate
  ,syJobType.Code AS [syJobType Code]
  ,syJobStatus.Code AS [syJobStatus Code]
  ,emLabour.LabourFirstName AS [First Name]
  ,emLabour.LabourSurName AS [Last Name]
  ,wojob.LabourID 
  ,count(*) over (partition by wojob.LabourID) as CountLabourIDs
 FROM
  woJob
    INNER JOIN syJobType
        ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID
    INNER JOIN syJobStatus
        ON woJob.JobStatusID = syJobStatus.JobStatusID
    INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour]
        ON woJob.LabourID = emLabour.LabourID

Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED')
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. please see comments within the script

```
SELECT
  wojob1.JobID
  ,wojob1.FullDescription
  ,wojob1.DueDate
  ,syJobType.Code AS [syJobType Code]
  ,syJobStatus.Code AS [syJobStatus Code]
  ,emLabour.LabourFirstName AS [First Name]
  ,emLabour.LabourSurName AS [Last Name]
  ,wojob1.LabourID 
  ,(Select count(1) from woJob  -- replaced
    INNER JOIN syJobType s1 --- alias
        ON woJob.JobTypeID = s1.JobTypeID
    INNER JOIN syJobStatus s2 --- alias
        ON woJob.JobStatusID = s2.JobStatusID
    INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour] em --- alias
        ON woJob.LabourID = em.LabourID 
     and wojob1.LabourID = woJob.LabourID   --added

Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED') 
        -- group by wojob.LabourID -- removed

        ) as CountLabourIDs
 FROM
  woJob as wojob1   -- alias
    INNER JOIN syJobType
        ON wojob1.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID
    INNER JOIN syJobStatus
        ON wojob1.JobStatusID = syJobStatus.JobStatusID
    INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour]
        ON wojob1.LabourID = emLabour.LabourID

Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
  With My_cte as (
      Select wojob.LabourID,count(wojob.LabourID) as Count_LabourID
      FROM woJob 
      INNER JOIN syJobType
        ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID
      INNER JOIN syJobStatus
        ON woJob.JobStatusID = syJobStatus.JobStatusID
      INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour]
        ON woJob.LabourID = emLabour.LabourID
      Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED') 
      group by wojob.LabourID
  )
  SELECT
  woJob.JobID
  ,woJob.FullDescription
  ,woJob.DueDate
  ,syJobType.Code AS [syJobType Code]
  ,syJobStatus.Code AS [syJobStatus Code]
  ,emLabour.LabourFirstName AS [First Name]
  ,emLabour.LabourSurName AS [Last Name]
  ,wojob.LabourID 
  ,Count_LabourID
 FROM
  woJob
    INNER JOIN syJobType
        ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID
    INNER JOIN syJobStatus
        ON woJob.JobStatusID = syJobStatus.JobStatusID
    INNER JOIN [Maint5k].[dbo].[emLabour]
        ON woJob.LabourID = emLabour.LabourID
    LEFT JOIN My_cte e on wojob.LabourID = e.wojob.LabourID

Where syJobType.Code = 'PM' and
        DueDate < GETDATE() and
        (syjobstatus.Code = 'Open' or
        syJobStatus.Code = 'SCHEDULED')
```